# python : matplotlib.Basemap.scatter does not show all points on map

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm actually trying to plot points on a map. Each points is associated to a value beetween 0 and 1000 in `sumlist`. I just want to color the points with a proportional red component as you can see on this reproducible exemple :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

m = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0,lat_0=0,resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='#ddaa66',lake_color='#7777ff')
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,420.,60.))
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#7777ff')

lon_prox=[-36.4,-38.5,-77,-71,-19.8,-69.5,-10.09,-4.93,9,-91.3,-85.92,-114.2,-109.3,103,-110.1,-42.6,1.16,-20.1,-23.2,-18.2,-17.95,-17.7,-10.1,-5.87]
lat_prox=[76.6,72.6,80.7,69.87,64.6,81.33,30.845,58.14,46,35.15,30.45,38.9,37.5,71.29,40,71.7,40.34,57.44,56.1,66.54,66.53,66.55,30.85,56.67]
x,y=m(lon_prox,lat_prox)

sumlist=[276,554,39,0,2,1,107,14,10,32,0,992,933,17,897,39,0,0,0,0,0,24,111,0]

for i in range(len(x)):
    col='#%02x%02x%02x' % (int((255*sumlist[i])/1000),0,0)
    m.scatter(x[i],y[i],color=col,zorder=10)

plt.show()
```

The problem is that all the points are not shown on the map. I'm thinking that the `zorder`parameter could helps me because when I set it to `10` (I put nothing before) some points that I had not appeared. But I don't really understand what does `zorder`. I know that the problem should not be really difficult to solve but I spent two hours on it.

Thanks in advance,

Smich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scatter() takes x, y, c lists or arrays as parameters. Try this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
#import numpy as np

# defind figure dimension
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

m = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0,lat_0=0,resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines(color='gray')
m.fillcontinents(color='#ddaa66',lake_color='#7777ff')
m.drawmeridians(range(0,420,60))
m.drawparallels(range(-90,120,30))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#7777ff')

lon_prox=[-36.4,-38.5,-77,-71,-19.8,-69.5,-10.09,-4.93,9,-91.3,-85.92,-114.2,-109.3,103,-110.1,-42.6,1.16,-20.1,-23.2,-18.2,-17.95,-17.7,-10.1,-5.87]
lat_prox=[76.6,72.6,80.7,69.87,64.6,81.33,30.845,58.14,46,35.15,30.45,38.9,37.5,71.29,40,71.7,40.34,57.44,56.1,66.54,66.53,66.55,30.85,56.67]
x,y=m(lon_prox, lat_prox)

sumlist=[276,554,39,0,2,1,107,14,10,32,0,992,933,17,897,39,0,0,0,0,0,24,111,0]

# prep colors
hexcolors = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    hexcolors.append('#%02x%02x%02x' % (int((255*sumlist[i])/max(sumlist)),0,0))

# scatter takes x,y,c arrays as parameters
m.scatter(x, y, c=hexcolors, s=60, zorder=10, alpha=0.7) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your good answer, that works for me :) Bye